# Fail to minify the code from; firestore/src/validate.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a React app using Firebase for the back-end and Firebase for the hosting as well. While running yarn build in the terminal I get the following error message;

> juneau:5-3-1-app JD$ yarn build yarn run v1.2.1 $ react-scripts build
>   Creating an optimized production build... **Failed to compile**.

Failed to minify the code from this file:

./node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/validate.js:27

> **Error** Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit
>   //yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/93